# Запросы отношений в трехсторонней сводной таблице

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, relationship

Мне выпала задача поработать с трехсторонней сводной таблицей, однако я никак не могу получить все свойства и их значения для конкретного товара.

У меня три модели **Product**, **Property** и **PropertyValue**.

Модель **Product**:

```
public function properties() :BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class,'product_property', 'product_id', 'property_id')
            ->with('values')
            ->withPivot('property_value_id')
            ->orderBy('order');
    }

public function values() :BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PropertyValue::class,'product_property', 'product_id', 'property_value_id');
    }
```

Модель **Property**:

```
public function products() :BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_property', 'property_id', 'product_id');
    }

    public function values() :BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PropertyValue::class, 'product_property','property_id','property_value_id')->withPivot('product_id');
    }
```

Модель **PropertyValue**:

```
public function properties() :BelongsToMany
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany(Property::class, 'product_property','property_id','property_value_id');
}

public function products() :BelongsToMany
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_property','property_value_id','product_id');
}
```

Миграция сводной таблицы **product_property**:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_property', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('property_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('property_value_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Я спокойно могу получить **Product** и далее получить либо его свойства **Property**

```
$product->properties
```

либо только значения его свойств **PropertyValue**

```
$product->values
```

Однако я никак не могу получить цепочку:

```
Товар->Его свойства->Значения этих свойств у выбранного товара.
```

Если я делаю что-то типа

```
$product->properties()->first()->values
```

то получаю все **PropertyValue** выбранного **Property** в сводной таблице, а не для конкретно выбранного **Product**.

Моя задача сложна тем, что я не могу внести никакие изменения в БД.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как не меняя сводную таблицу получить цепочку

```
Товар->Его свойства->Значения этих свойств у выбранного товара.
```